# Hard Question on Math Homework concerning chemical Mass of Molecules (Problem explained in Body)

Tags: algebra-precalculus, chemistry

A chemist wants to make a solution of 0.05mg of MgCl2 in 52.51mL of H2O; however, he only has MgCl2 * 6H2O to make  his solution.  How much water should he add if he  has to make  the correct concentration.

Note:  The MgCl2 is  53.2% of the total MgCl2 * 6H2O Compound.

Note:  In Order for the solution to remain the same,  the water from the  6H2O binds with the water  that will be added.

(I have been trying for 3 hours now)   (This was given on an Algebra 2 Test Review Sheet.)

Comment: instead of mentioning "I have been trying for 3 hours now", Try adding "This is what I have tried...."